# align one set of 2d points with another using only translation and rotation

Tags: math, opencv, geometry, rotation, translation

I'm working in OpenCV but I don't think there is a function for this. I can find a function for finding affine transformations, but affine transformations include scaling, and I only want to consider rotation + translation.

Imagine I have two sets of points in 2d - let's say each set has exactly 50 points.

E.g. set A = {x1, y1, x2, y2, ... , x50, y50}

set B = {x1', y1', x2', y2', ... , x50', y50'}

I want to find the rotation and translation combination that gets closest to mapping set A onto set B. I guess I would define "closest" as minimises the average distance between points in A and corresponding points in B. I.e., minimises the average distance between (x1, y1) and (x1', y1'), etc.

I guess I could use brute force testing all possible translations and rotations but this would be extremely inefficient. Does anyone know a simpler way?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a one-to-one correspondence between points? Are they really the same point and you just need to find the transformation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem has a very elegant solution in terms of singular value decomposition of the proximity matrix (distances between pairs of points).  The name of this is the [orthogonal Procrustes problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem), after the Greek legend about a fellow who offered travellers a bed that would fit anyone.

The solution comes from finding the nearest orthogonal matrix to a given (not necessarily orthogonal) matrix.

Comment: thanks. I found the same solution around about the time that you posted your answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_analysis

Comment: @Andrew: It's a neat/surprising application of SVD, it seems to me.  The solution by Peter Schonemann was motivated by an application to testing metrics in psychology/social sciences.  To be sure if you mean to rule out reflections (as opposed to translations and rotations), a little tweaking of the singular values is required.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it in Excel is to make a couple columns representing the points.
Cells representing rotation/translation of a set (no need to rotate and translate both of them).
Then columns representing those same points rotated/translated.
Then another column for the distance between the points of the rotated/translated points.
Then a cell of the sum of the distances between points.
Finally, use Solver to optimize the rotation and translation cells.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i was able to do what i needed by calculating the mean point for each set to calculate the translation, and then using this page to figure out the rotation angle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_analysis

Answer (score 0):

If you fix some rotation you can get an answer using [ternary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search). Run search in x and for every tested x run it in y to get the best value. This will give you the correct answer since the function (sum of corresponding distances) is convex (this can be proved through observing that restriction of the function to any line is a one-dimensional convex function; and the last is a standard fact: the sum of several convex functions is convex).
Instead of brute force over the angle I can propose such a method based on the ternary search. Choose some not very large step S. Compute the target function for every angle in (0, S, 2S,...). Then, if S is small enough, we can exclude some of segments (iS, (i + 1)S) from consideration. Namely ones with relatively large values of function with angles iS and (i + 1)S. Being implemented carefully this can give an answer and can do it faster than brute force.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i was able to do what i needed by calculating the mean point for each set to calculate the translation, and then using this page to figure out the rotation angle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_analysis

Comment: You won't get any good approximation to the answer using mean point even in one-dimensional case. For example: one set (0, 2, 100) with mean 34, another is (0, 50, 100) with mean 50. After moving you'll get (16, 18, 116) and result of 16+32+16=64. But if you don't move you'll get just 48. And even rotating on the plane won't help here.

Comment: @SergeyBankevich: Using the mean as the translation minimizes the mean **square** distance, which tends to be more valuable than the mean distance

Comment: @Eric: You are right. But the question was about mean distance. Anyway, it seems the author was not very definite about distance measure and finally could have ended with your one.